# anaconda prompt, install pytorch manually, when import get "C++ Redistributable is not installed" error

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

What I did is as following:

1. In anaconda prompt, create a new virtual environment with python version=3.6, and activate it.
2. Download the pytorch .whl file whose version matches my computer (python3.6 cuda10.2)
3. Using "pip install filepath\torch-1.8.1+cu102-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" to install pytorch/

Then I launched the python in anaconda prompt, and tried to import torch, I get the following error:

"""
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is not installed, this may lead to the DLL load failure.
It can be downloaded at https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

OSError: [WinError 193]  Error loading "D:\software\anaconda\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\asmjit.dll" or one of its dependencies.
"""

There is a similar post [when importing pytorch microsoft visual C++ Redistributable is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212096/when-importing-pytorch-microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-is-not-installed). But even after I installed the visual c++ from the link, and restarted my computer, I still get the same error.

I think possible reasons could be:

1. I just download the "torch-1.8.1+cu102-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" file and installed it manully, but on the pytorch whl archive, I also see whl files for torchvison and torchcsprng. Maybe my installation is not compelete.
2. Some posts said anaconda should be installed in C drive. But I installed it in D drive.

My OS is windows, and my python version is 3.6.

Comment: Did you try the command suggested in pytorch.org ?

Comment: `pip3 install torch==1.8.1+cu102 torchvision==0.9.1+cu102 torchaudio===0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Comment: It could also be because you run installer with admin, and run prompt without admin, or vice versa

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen, Sorry for the late response. I tried this command several time and it did not work. That's reason I want to install pytorch manually. But after I turned off my vpn, the command on the official website works! Really  thanks for your advice!